# Can I declare a dependency like private package using Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin?

Tags: dependencies, osgi, maven-plugin, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

Can I declare a dependency like private package using Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin?

I would like to avoid NoClassDefFoundException due to different version of a transitive dependency.

Following [Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) I can see `<Private-Package>org.apache.felix.log.impl</Private-Package>`, but in that example the dependency which is declared as private is an own class.

I do not know if that statement could work with a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Private-Package for a package that is located inside a dependency. The result will be that the content of the package is embedded into your bundle.

Be careful though as this will cause Import-Package statements for all of the imports of all classes in this package. So in effect in can make your situation even worse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought that, but I would like to know how Eclipse solve this problem. Maybe Eclipse uses something like [BND](http://bndtools.org/)? In this case, BND is compatible with OSGi bundles?

Comment: What do you mean by Eclipse? Eclipse RCP or the plugin perspective of the IDE? It currently does not use bnd.

Comment: Eclipse solve this problem, if you look at Dependency section in a pom.xml file, you can see as Eclipse replaces transitive dependency with the most current one provided by other dependency. Do you understand?

Comment: Now I get what you mean. This is the logic of maven or in eclipse the m2e plugin. In OSGi these dependencies are not relevant. You express your dependencies using Import-Package with a package and a version range.
This is what then decides at Runtime which bundle can offer such a package.

OSGi will also use the highest version number of a package that fits the Import version range.

Comment: I will do that, I hope that works. I will tell you about that in the future. Thanks for your help! ;)